# Trying to locate a (resettable?) fuse that I believe may have blown entirely

Tags: identification, fuses

I am led to believe that there is at least one (potentially resettable) fuse on this Bosch manufactured BMW PDC module. I am also led to believe it has a limit to the number of times it can blow and has reached this limit, or if not resettable, has blown.

Firstly, is there one on this board at all and secondly which component is it and how can I identify what it is to order a replacement?

(Two photos of the same board with different lighting)

[image: Bosch BMW PDC PCB]

[image: Bosch BMW PDC PCB]

Comment: There's a chunky diode to the top right, probably a reverse polarity protection. If it went open (quite unlikely as the p-n junctions generally go short when broken) then the system can't work. Another possibility is that the MCU/MPU might have kept some error logs and decided not to operate, accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, I'm getting 0.37v when I test that with my multimeter and 0v when testing with reverse polarity so am I right in thinking that's not bad? The board does power up and I can communicate on the CAN BUS but there's no voltage going to the sensors.

Comment: I can’t see anything obvious in terms of a fuse. There doesn’t look like there are any high current outputs on the board but it does look like it would control relays. Have you tried to rule out the simpler and more obvious failure points before presuming something more complex? Have you run diagnostics on the vehicle to pinpoint what the module is unhappy about?

Comment: Yeah, diagnostics show that the module is reporting no voltage to the sensors (the module is still online). What's strange is that this module does both front and rear sensors, so you'd have thought that at least one of the circuits would be complete, but the fact that both the front and rears are dead, leads me to the module being at fault. It can't be wiring in the car because the harnesses are separate. There are no other fuses in the car which relate to PDC, so I think I'm going to have to swap out the module as I'm not experienced enough to fully test this, at least not without schematics

Comment: What connector/pin are the sensors powered from? Knowing this, you can trace on the pcb where the power comes from. This looks like a fairly simple module and can derive the schematic pretty much just by looking at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no self-resetting fuses on that board.

If the board disables itself after a number of events, then that's done in software and it's stored in EEPROM. Both are located in the microcontroller, the large square IC at the bottom left. Not something you can change.